# How to create a new xml using the content of an existing xml

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Per my requirement, I have to form a new xml with the content within the tags `<Final-Results>...</Final-Results>` from the following xml string. I need all the nodes, elements and their values between the said tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <response>
      <response>
         <PQCaseInquiry>
            <userID>12345</userID>
            <password>XXX</password>
            <hostAddress>10.193.236.57</hostAddress>
            <hostPort>12955</hostPort>
            <fromDate>2014-02-01-00.00.00.000000</fromDate>
            <toDate>2014-04-02-23.59.59.999999</toDate>
            <FOLDTYPE>GROUP</FOLDTYPE>
            <FOLDERID>COMM*H</FOLDERID>
         </PQCaseInquiry>
         <tempfolder>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2012-08-31-08.26.11.805400</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>F</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <FKEY>2012-08-31-08.26.11.805400F01</FKEY>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <FOLDTYPE>GROUP</FOLDTYPE>
               <FOLDERID>COMM*H</FOLDERID>
               <lastCRDATTIM>
                  <CRDATTIM>2014-03-25-07.23.44.746840</CRDATTIM>
               </lastCRDATTIM>
               <row>
                  <row>
                     <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.22.22.339840</CRDATTIM>
                     <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
                     <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
                     <CKEY>2014-03-26-05.22.22.339840C01</CKEY>
                     <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
                     <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
                     <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
                     <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
                     <STPTIM>2014-03-26-15.52.21.000000</STPTIM>
                     <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
                     <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
                  </row>
                  <row>
                     <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.05.51.531840</CRDATTIM>
                     <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
                     <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
                     <CKEY>2014-03-26-05.05.51.531840C01</CKEY>
                     <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
                     <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
                     <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
                     <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
                     <STPTIM>2014-03-26-15.35.50.000000</STPTIM>
                     <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
                     <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
                  </row>
                  <row>
                     <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.00.28.231840</CRDATTIM>
                     <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
                     <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
                     <CKEY>2014-03-26-05.00.28.231840C01</CKEY>
                     <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
                     <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
                     <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
                     <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
                     <STPTIM>2014-03-26-15.30.26.000000</STPTIM>
                     <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
                     <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
                  </row>
                  <row>
                     <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-01.44.49.527840</CRDATTIM>
                     <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
                     <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
                     <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.44.49.527840C01</CKEY>
                     <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
                     <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
                     <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
                     <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
                     <STPTIM>2014-03-26-12.14.48.000000</STPTIM>
                     <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
                     <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
                  </row>
                  <row>
                     <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-01.40.52.728840</CRDATTIM>
                     <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
                     <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
                     <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.40.52.728840C01</CKEY>
                     <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
                     <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
                     <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
                     <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
                     <STPTIM>2014-03-26-12.10.51.000000</STPTIM>
                     <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
                     <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
                  </row>
                  <row>
                     <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-01.36.16.402840</CRDATTIM>
                     <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
                     <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
                     <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.36.16.402840C01</CKEY>
                     <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
                     <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
                     <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
                     <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
                     <STPTIM>2014-03-26-12.06.15.000000</STPTIM>
                     <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
                     <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
                  </row>
                  <row>
                     <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-01.34.17.928840</CRDATTIM>
                     <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
                     <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
                     <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.34.17.928840C01</CKEY>
                     <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
                     <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
                     <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
                     <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
                     <STPTIM>2014-03-26-12.04.16.000000</STPTIM>
                     <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
                     <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
                  </row>
                  <row>
                     <CRDATTIM>2014-03-25-07.55.16.612840</CRDATTIM>
                     <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
                     <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
                     <CKEY>2014-03-25-07.55.16.612840C01</CKEY>
                     <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
                     <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
                     <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
                     <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
                     <STPTIM>2014-03-25-18.25.15.000000</STPTIM>
                     <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
                     <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
                  </row>
                  <row>
                     <CRDATTIM>2014-03-25-07.35.15.992840</CRDATTIM>
                     <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
                     <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
                     <CKEY>2014-03-25-07.35.15.992840C01</CKEY>
                     <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
                     <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
                     <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
                     <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
                     <STPTIM>2014-03-25-18.05.14.000000</STPTIM>
                     <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
                     <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
                  </row>
                  <row>
                     <CRDATTIM>2014-03-25-07.23.44.746840</CRDATTIM>
                     <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
                     <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
                     <CKEY>2014-03-25-07.23.44.746840C01</CKEY>
                     <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
                     <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
                     <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
                     <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
                     <STPTIM>2014-03-25-17.53.43.000000</STPTIM>
                     <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
                     <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
                  </row>
               </row>
            </row>
         </tempfolder>
         <TempFolders>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2012-11-06-23.57.08.089400</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>F</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <FKEY>2012-11-06-23.57.08.089400F01</FKEY>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCDV</UNITCD>
               <FOLDTYPE>GROUP</FOLDTYPE>
               <FOLDERID>COMM*H</FOLDERID>
            </row>
         </TempFolders>
         <CaseCount>10</CaseCount>
      </response>
      <results>
         <PQCLKUP-Results>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.22.22.339840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-05.22.22.339840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-15.52.21.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.05.51.531840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-05.05.51.531840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-15.35.50.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.00.28.231840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-05.00.28.231840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-15.30.26.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-01.44.49.527840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.44.49.527840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-12.14.48.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-01.40.52.728840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.40.52.728840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-12.10.51.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-01.36.16.402840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.36.16.402840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-12.06.15.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-01.34.17.928840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.34.17.928840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-12.04.16.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-25-07.55.16.612840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-25-07.55.16.612840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-25-18.25.15.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-25-07.35.15.992840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-25-07.35.15.992840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-25-18.05.14.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-25-07.23.44.746840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-25-07.23.44.746840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-25-17.53.43.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
         </PQCLKUP-Results>
         <cases>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.05.51.531840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-05.05.51.531840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-15.35.50.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.00.28.231840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-05.00.28.231840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-15.30.26.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-01.44.49.527840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.44.49.527840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-12.14.48.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-01.40.52.728840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.40.52.728840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-12.10.51.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-01.36.16.402840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.36.16.402840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-12.06.15.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-01.34.17.928840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.34.17.928840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-26-12.04.16.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-25-07.55.16.612840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-25-07.55.16.612840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-25-18.25.15.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-25-07.35.15.992840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-25-07.35.15.992840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-25-18.05.14.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
            <row>
               <CRDATTIM>2014-03-25-07.23.44.746840</CRDATTIM>
               <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
               <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
               <CKEY>2014-03-25-07.23.44.746840C01</CKEY>
               <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
               <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
               <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
               <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
               <STPTIM>2014-03-25-17.53.43.000000</STPTIM>
               <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
               <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            </row>
         </cases>
         <KEY>
            <CKEY>2014-03-26-05.22.22.339840C01</CKEY>
            <CKEY>2014-03-26-05.05.51.531840C01</CKEY>
            <CKEY>2014-03-26-05.00.28.231840C01</CKEY>
            <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.44.49.527840C01</CKEY>
            <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.40.52.728840C01</CKEY>
            <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.36.16.402840C01</CKEY>
            <CKEY>2014-03-26-01.34.17.928840C01</CKEY>
            <CKEY>2014-03-25-07.55.16.612840C01</CKEY>
            <CKEY>2014-03-25-07.35.15.992840C01</CKEY>
            <CKEY>2014-03-25-07.23.44.746840C01</CKEY>
         </KEY>
      </results>
      <Final-Results>
         <row>
            <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.22.22.339840</CRDATTIM>
            <RECORDCD>C</RECORDCD>
            <CRNODE>01</CRNODE>
            <CKEY>2014-03-26-05.22.22.339840C01</CKEY>
            <STATCD>CREATED</STATCD>
            <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
            <WRKTYPE>CALL</WRKTYPE>
            <QUEUECD>END</QUEUECD>
            <STPTIM>2014-03-26-15.52.21.000000</STPTIM>
            <CMOOD>Happy</CMOOD>
            <CMEDIA>Phone</CMEDIA>
            <issues>
               <row>
                  <IKEY>2014-03-26-05.22.22.193840T01</IKEY>
                  <PRTY>999</PRTY>
                  <ISSUEID>20140326-155047-DT81694</ISSUEID>
                  <SUBJECT>Group</SUBJECT>
                  <ISSTYP>GROUP</ISSTYP>
                  <ISSCAT1>GROUP INQUIRY</ISSCAT1>
                  <RELMEM />
                  <RELGRP>COMM*H</RELGRP>
                  <RELPRV />
                  <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
                  <WRKTYPE>ISSUE</WRKTYPE>
                  <STATCD>CATCHALL</STATCD>
                  <QUEUECD>CATCHALL</QUEUECD>
                  <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.22.22.193840</CRDATTIM>
                  <LOCKSTAT />
                  <ORIGUSERID>DT81694</ORIGUSERID>
                  <STPTIM>2014-03-26-15.50.47.000000</STPTIM>
                  <RELPRVTYP />
                  <RELCLM />
                  <RELCLMBEGDOS />
                  <RELCLMENDDOS />
                  <RELAUTH />
                  <RELAUTHBEGDOS />
                  <RELAUTHENDDOS />
                  <ST_CHG_DATTIM>2014-03-26-05.24.59.464840</ST_CHG_DATTIM>
                  <END_QUEUE_FLG>N</END_QUEUE_FLG>
                  <ASSIGNID />
                  <LOCKWORK_FLG />
               </row>
            </issues>
         </row>
      </Final-Results>
      <CaseCount>10</CaseCount>
   </response>
   <results>
      <row>
         <IKEY>2014-03-26-05.22.22.193840T01</IKEY>
         <PRTY>999</PRTY>
         <ISSUEID>20140326-155047-DT81694</ISSUEID>
         <SUBJECT>Group</SUBJECT>
         <ISSTYP>GROUP</ISSTYP>
         <ISSCAT1>GROUP INQUIRY</ISSCAT1>
         <RELMEM />
         <RELGRP>COMM*H</RELGRP>
         <RELPRV />
         <UNITCD>CSMHCQA</UNITCD>
         <WRKTYPE>ISSUE</WRKTYPE>
         <STATCD>CATCHALL</STATCD>
         <QUEUECD>CATCHALL</QUEUECD>
         <CRDATTIM>2014-03-26-05.22.22.193840</CRDATTIM>
         <LOCKSTAT />
         <ORIGUSERID>DT81694</ORIGUSERID>
         <STPTIM>2014-03-26-15.50.47.000000</STPTIM>
         <RELPRVTYP />
         <RELCLM />
         <RELCLMBEGDOS />
         <RELCLMENDDOS />
         <RELAUTH />
         <RELAUTHBEGDOS />
         <RELAUTHENDDOS />
         <ST_CHG_DATTIM>2014-03-26-05.24.59.464840</ST_CHG_DATTIM>
         <END_QUEUE_FLG>N</END_QUEUE_FLG>
         <ASSIGNID />
         <LOCKWORK_FLG />
      </row>
   </results>
</response>
```

I have tried with the following piece of Java code:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
 org.w3c.dom.NodeList titleNodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//Final-Results", xmlString, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

I am getting the following exception with the above code:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unable to evaluate expression using this context
```

Am I doing any thing wrong here? Could you please share your ideas with some pseudo code to achieve my functionality if my approach is wrong?

Comment: Seriously, did you *really* need to include a 5+ page XML example?

Comment: I have added the complete xml to illustrate that my xml has several nodes and elements from which I need specific set of data as xml.

Comment: I request the people who down voted my post to leave a comment so that I can correct my self if required.

Comment: I think we've done that.

Comment: Cool..!! If all the persons who have down voted my post with the same reason that you have mentioned, then its okay! I have added a reply too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with several approaches. But,the following code worked for me:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;

import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;


Reader xml = new StringReader("<xml />");
             Document document  = null;
             SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
              document = reader.read(xml);

              List <Element> elements = getXmlElements(document,"//Final-Results");
for(int index = 0; index < elements.size();index ++){
                    Element element = elements.get(index);
System.out.println("The required xml "+element.asXML())
}
```

getXmlElements() method is here:

```
private List<Element> getXmlElements(Document document,String xPath) {
             List<Element> elements = document.selectNodes(xPath);
            return elements;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to execute something like this:

```
NodeList list = (NodeList) XPathFactory.newInstance()
    .newXPath()
    .evaluate("/xml", "<xml />", XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

However, *String* is [not a supported argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#evaluate-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-javax.xml.namespace.QName-). The implementation expects a [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html). Provide an [InputSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/InputSource.html):

```
Reader xml = new StringReader("<xml />");
InputSource src = new InputSource(xml);
NodeList list = (NodeList) XPathFactory.newInstance()
    .newXPath()
    .evaluate("/xml", src, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Assuming the XML is a file, supply a binary *InputStream* and let the XML parser detect the character encoding.

Comment: Thanks.But the above code will print the values. i.e the output will consists of only values, not the tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse("test.xml");
    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    org.w3c.dom.NodeList titleNodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//tempfolder", doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("out.xml"));

    for(int i=0;i<titleNodes.getLength();i++){
        Node node = titleNodes.item(i);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(node);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
    }
```